# Angle of analyticity of semigroup

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, semigroups-of-operators, analytic-functions

Is there any known parabolic PDEs in the literature where the angle of analyticity of the associated semigroup is $<\pi/2$ ?

For example, the angle of heat semigroup in $L^2$ is exactly $=\pi/2$. I'm wondering if there is a known example where the angle is e.g., $\pi/4$ or other value $< \pi/2$.

Comment: Yes, such examples are known. For some references, see for instance Secion 7.2.6 in "W. Arendt: Semigroups and Evolution Equations: Functional Calculus, Regularity and Kernel Estimates (2004)".

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you. The example given is about the realization of the semigroup in $L^p$. Do you know any example in Hilbert space, say $L^2$ for example?

Comment: Good question... Are you interested in real coefficients only, or also in PDEs with complex coefficients?

Comment: Yes I'm interested in real coefficients, but if necessary no problem with complex ones.

Comment: With complex coefficients it's quite easy: just consider the PDE $\dot u = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u$ on, say, $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (though one might argue whether this is really a "parabolic" PDE). I don't know an example with real coefficients at the moment, but I would suspect that such examples exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Too long for a comment. Actually I do not think that it is written anywhere but these kind of counterexamples are usually provided by the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup, generated by $\Delta+Bx \cdot \nabla$, where $B$ is a matrix. Assuming that all eigenvalues of $B$ have negative real parts, then an invariant measure $\mu$ exists (and is given by a Gaussian density). It turns out that the angle of analiticity in $L^p$ of the invariant measure can be computed exactly and can be smaller than $\pi/2$, even for $p=2$. This can be found in a paper by Chill, Fasangova, Pallara and myself.

*Chill, R.; Fašangová, E.; Metafune, G.; Pallara, D.*, [**The sector of analyticity of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup on (L^p) spaces with respect to invariant measure**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0024610705006344), J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 71, No. 3, 703-722 (2005). [ZBL1123.35030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1123.35030).

To obtain similar examples in unweighted spaces one has only (but patiently) to compensate the weight thus obtaining an operator with a linear drift and a quadratic potential. This works however only from dimension $2$ on; in the one dimensional case the operator is always self-adjont but still the angle of analitycity is different from $\pi/2$ in $L^p$, for $p$ different from $2$. There is also a paper by E. Priola and myself dealing with non-analytic Markov semigroups where one finds other examples.

*Metafune, G.; Priola, E.*, [**Some classes of non-analytic Markov semigroups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2004.02.037), J. Math. Anal. Appl. 294, No. 2, 596-613 (2004). [ZBL1067.47055](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1067.47055).

It would be nice to have a direct approach, avoiding the detour.

Answer (score 3):

There are examples but you need singularities or unbounded coefficients; the uniformly parabolic case with regular coefficients is indeed a perturbation of the laplacian. In 1D, if you perturb the harmonic oscillator $D^2-x^2$ by a linear drift $bxD$, the angle of analyticity depends on $b$.